# Looking for good data source for back testing and Monte Carlo

Tags: finance, data

Does anyone know of a freely available data source that will have American and foreign stocks, mutual fund, and ETF info including stock's histories of paying dividends, PTB and PTE ratios, as well as options, forward and future contracts, currencies, and REITs? End of day resolution would be fine. Thank you!